# I am unable to use vue render functions to render Vuetify uicomponents (v-app-bar, v-navigation-in a standalone vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

### Main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

### App.vue

```
template>
  <v-app>
    <Navbar/>
    <div>
      <v-content  class="mx-4 mb-4">
        <router-view></router-view>
      </v-content>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar'

export default {
  name: 'App',

  components: {
    Navbar
  },

  data: () => ({
    //
  }),
};
</script>
```

### Navbar.vue (current)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-app-bar app flat color="">
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>
        <span>Sample App</span>
      </v-toolbar-title>
    </v-app-bar>
  </div>
</template>
....
....
```

### Navbar.vue (desired)

```
no template because I want to use render function
<script>
export default {
...
...
  render(createElement){
    const icon = createElement('v-app-bar-nav-icon')
    return createElement('v-app-bar', [icon])
...
...
}
}
```

When I try this I get an errors:
vue.common.dev.js?4650:630 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm. Why do you need to use render here?

Comment: Trying to create a generator for vue components.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:

You simply have to import the vuetify components manually into the vue component.

**Navbar.vue**

```
<script>
import { VAppBar, VAppBarNavIcon } from "vuetify/lib";

export default {
  render(createElement) {
    const icon = createElement(VAppBarNavIcon)
    return createElement(VAppBar, {}, [icon]);
  },
};
</script>
```

More info at this [link](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/#manually-importing).